# node.js server wont listen to the port or server blocks the connections to this port

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, livechat

I have a real time chat in my project, The project is base on Laravel and the chat is with node.js and socket.io. 
I have a problem with connecting to the port that my node.js server file open my server file codes is:

```
var express = require("express"), http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
// var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(52437);

console.log("executed");

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("connnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnectedddddddddddd");
});
```

this codes in in a file in directory public_html/build/js/server.js with permition 755.
When I run this command in shell on server:

```
node public_html/build/js/server.js
```

the console.log('execute') will execute and "executed" will print in shell so the file exists and node server will run am I right?

This node server is listening to port 52437 so it should be an open port right?
but when I try this command from my terminal:

```
telnet [domain or IP] 57329
```

After 5 to 10 second it return a connection time out.
Can someone help me What is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is server.js in a public directory?

Comment: I have tried creating server listening on port 57329, It works in mine.

Comment: Is it wrong? I don't know if it's wrong or not but the file will execute! @JorgeCabrera

Comment: So what is wrong what is directory you created node server file? @MehulPrajapati

Comment: I see you are testing, but of course is wrong. Server should not be in a public directory

Comment: Are you telneting to localhost? `telnet localhost 57329`?

Comment: I changed the directory to root but problem still exists @JorgeCabrera

Comment: from my laptop I do this: telnet www.site.com 52437 @JorgeCabrera

Comment: But you are not serving the web in the outside, you are running it locally. Try to `telnet localhost 57329`

Comment: The file server.js I am running is on server on web, I am running node server bye shell access to the server! @JorgeCabrera

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153234/discussion-between-jorge-cabrera-and-hassan-shojaei).